# How to get receipt handle from sqs queue response, getting(TypeError 'sqs.Message' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-sqs

I have one queue I'm sending some message in that and want to get receipt handle from output response.

```
messages = queue.receive_messages()
print(messages)
```

I am receiving this type of response:

```
[sqs.Message(queue_url='someurl', receipt_handle='abcd')]
```

Now I want to extract only receipt handle from the response,
here what I have tried

```
message = messages[0]
receipt_handle = message['receipt_handle']
print(receipt_handle)
```

but I'm getting below error:

```
TypeError 'sqs.Message' object is not subscriptable
```

How can I get receipt_handle from response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sqs.Message` object uses attributes:

```
message.receipt_handle
```

See the documentation: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sqs.html#message

---

Your attempt only works if you use the boto3-client, then the response is a dict. See https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sqs.html#message